# ¿A partir de una fecha ingresada,como saber el día,fecha y hora?

Tags: python, date, if, while

A partir de una fecha ingresada cualquiera,como puedo yo sumarle otra cantidad de dias ingresados para que me de la nueva fecha?

```
D=int(input("Ingresar dia de la fecha:"))  
while D<0 or D>31:  
    print("Dia no válido")
    D=int(input("Ingresar dia de la fecha:"))

M=int(input("Ingresar mes correspondiente:"))  
while M<0 or M>12:  
    print("Mes no válido")
    M=int(input("Ingresar mes:"))

A=int(input("Ingresar año correspondiente:"))  
while A<0:  
    print("Año no valido")
    A=int(input("Ingresar año:"))

FI=int(input("Ingrese fecha a saber:"))  
while FI<0:  
    print("No es válido")
    FI=int(input("Ingresar fecha a saber:"))
if FI>=365:  
    print(D,M,(A+1))
```

Si lo hago asi con IF me llevaria muchisimo declarar todas las posibilidades,como deberia hacerlo de manera sencilla?

Comment: ¿Por alguna razón lo debes resolver de esta forma? Usando un objeto `date`  es bastante más sencillo de resolver, ¿te serviría una solución en ese sentido?

Comment: me serviria pero no lo vi en la uni y me lo piden de esa manera en especifico o con un while, pero si fuera con date como seria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando el módulo `datetime` de python es trivial, porque él incluye todo lo necesario para convertir cadenas que representan fechas en su representación interna de fecha y operadores para sumar/restar etc estas fechas y volver a imprimirlas.

Por ejemplo:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
fecha = input("Introduzca fecha (YYYY-MM-DD): ")
try:
  fecha = datetime.strptime(fecha, "%Y-%m-%d")
except:
  print("La fecha no tiene el formato correcto")
else:
  delta = input("Introduzca número de días transcurridos: ")
  delta = int(delta)
  final = fecha + timedelta(days=delta)
  print(final.date())
```

Ejemplo de ejecución:

```
Introduzca fecha (YYYY-MM-DD): 2018-2-27
Introduzca número de días transcurridos: 7
2018-03-06
```

Ahora bien, entiendo que esta solución no es válida en tu caso porque se trata de un ejercicio de introducción a la programación, en la que tú mismo debes codificar lo que `datetime` ya te da hecho.

En este caso una solución sencilla podría ser convertir la fecha que te ha dado el usuario en un entero que represente el número de días transcurridos desde el inicio del año. Para ello puedes tener una lista con 12 elementos que son los días de cada mes, sumar todos los elementos hasta el mes que el usuario te haya dado (no incluido) y sumar a éste el día del mes.

A este entero le sumas el `delta` que te haya dado el usuario y tendrás otro entero que representa el número de días transcurridos desde el inicio del año de la primera fecha, hasta la fecha buscada. Tienes que convertir ese entero a año, mes y día, para lo cual puedes dividir por 365 para saber el número de años transcurridos, y quedarte con el resto para ver el número de días dentro del año destino. Después usarías de nuevo la lista de días por mes. Vas restando a ese entero los días de cada mes de esa lista, mientras el resultado sea positivo, para así encontrar en qué mes está. El día del mes será la cantidad restante.

La cosa se complica ligeramente si debes tener en cuenta años bisiestos. Habría que conocer las especificaciones concretas del problema para ver si sería necesario abordar esos casos.